# Filling in missing timestamps in large dataset

Tags: r, time-series, timestamp

I am trying to fill missing datapoints in a large time series of eddy covariance data. it is in half hourly values in the following format: [timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7wh4.png)

the actual csv file is around 14000 lines long with ~200 columns.

I want to fill it so that any jumps in the timestamp (as shown in the sample) are filled with the correct time stamp as new lines where the data already aligned with a timestamp still stays with it, and the filled values other than timestamp, doy and date are filled.

Any help much appreciated. I have tried using zoo, tidyverse etc but cant get it to work. With these gaps it creates error when trying to gap fill.

I have tried a variety of packages to no avail. I kept getting a variety of errors, or just no changes to the data.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output.

Comment: You can try `time_completev()` from my package `timeplyr`. github.com/NicChr/timeplyr
I'll try and attempt a solution if you're able to share some data.
E.g. `time_completev(x, time_by = "30 minutes")`